# Custom HtmlHelper for multiple MVC apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on multiple ASP.NET MVC web apps.

All of these web apps have the same navigation bars/menus.
Some of the menu items are app specific, so they can be passed from the respective app.

Some of the menu items are not app-specific, such as whether user is admin or not, based on which I show an admin link on the nav bar. The logic for getting the admin property is available in the business layer.

Is it possible to make this html helper such that I don't have to pass the non-app specific parameters from the respective apps ? 
Can I call the business layer from the html helper ?

Is it advisable ?
I want this html helper or any other solution easily distributable...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML helpers are extension methods on the `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` type that return an `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString` object. If you want "easily distributable", then you can create a library project with the helper extensions that you need. Then add the project in as a reference on the MVC project.

`@using` statements can bring in the extensions to the Razor view. The `helper` object that you bring in through the extension method in the library will give you access to most of the information available to the Razor view at the time the helper is called (with the `ViewContext` property).

The extensions can be overloaded as much as needed to account for variations in the projects. Common menu options can be added to the library as a static collection that can be accessed by both the MVC project and the extension methods.

**update**

MVC is set up such that you can do what you want. You have a lot of control. Your helper can include as much code as you need. It's not like you are "breaking the rules". But best practice dictates that you keep your business logic in the controller. By putting that into the helper, which gets called by the Razor view, you are in effect moving the business logic into the Razor view.

HTML Helpers in general are a lightweight way to create HTML code. Thus they are easy to reuse any you can have dozens or hundreds on a single Razor view. That idea gets broken when you move a bunch of business logic into the helper. Then you have a potential of slowing things down if the helper is to be reused a lot.

Good rule of thumb for MVC, if your helper starts getting complicated, create a partial view. I would probably create a model to represent the menu, then create a partial view in the Shared folder that uses that model, then call it from the parent view. I think that would give you more flexibility, and be more in keeping with the MVC best practices.

Comment: I am already a HTML Helper. My question was : Should I be calling the business layer directly from the helper or every MVC app should call the business layer and pass me the admin property. I have seen people saying that you should not include business logic in Html Helpers...

Comment: Thanks ! I know what you mean. But if I create a partial view, that becomes un-distributable. Now, you cannot wrap it into a dll and share it, right ? The partial view has to live in the current MVC project.

Comment: The bottom line is that the work has to be done. Somewhere, the code has to exist, and has to run. It's not going to be faster or slower if it runs in the helper or the controller. Both get compiled into the project DLL. The rest is just optimization, readability, and best practice. If "best practice" gets into a gray area, put it where it makes the most sense for your application(s).